# refactoring: How can I improve this as a clean code

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I am currently studying JS myself.
And make the pig-game which is project of the course that I watched.
 I'm always curious how can I improve my code but I got no idea where do I begin. 
Is there some principle that I can improve any code?
If there's a way, Could you let me know?
 Thanks!

https://github.com/wonkooklee/pig-game

 result : https://wonkooklee.github.io/pig-game/

below is main functions

```
document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  if (gamePlaying) {
    
    dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
    diceDOM.src = `dice-${dice}.png`;

    if (dice === 6 && lastDice === 6) {
      // Player looses score
      scores[activePlayer] = 0;
      document.getElementById(`score-${activePlayer}`).textContent = '0';
      nextPlayer();
    } else if (dice !== 1 && dice !== 6) {
      roundScore += dice;
      document.getElementById(`current-${activePlayer}`).textContent = roundScore;
      lastDice = 0;
    } else if (dice === 6) {
      roundScore += dice;
      document.getElementById(`current-${activePlayer}`).textContent = roundScore;
      lastDice = dice;
    } else {
      nextPlayer();
    }


  }

});

document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (gamePlaying) {
    scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;
    document.getElementById(`score-${activePlayer}`).textContent = scores[activePlayer];

    let input = document.getElementById('scoreSet').value;
    let winningScore;

    if (isNaN(input) === false) {
      winningScore = input;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('scoreSet').value = '100';
    }

    if (scores[activePlayer] >= winningScore) {

      document.getElementById(`name-${activePlayer}`).textContent = 'WINNER!';
      document.querySelector(`.player-${activePlayer}-panel`).classList.add('winner');
      document.querySelector(`.player-${activePlayer}-panel`).classList.remove('active');
      diceDOM.style.display = 'none';
      gamePlaying = false;
    } else {
      nextPlayer();
    }

  }

});
```

[image: my pig-game]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin Fowler wrote a great book ["Refactoring"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134757599). Besides, Fowler has a great blog [Refactoring.com](https://refactoring.com/), where you can find a lot of information about refactoring with examples in Javascript.
I'm not strong in Javascript, but can let you some advices about your code.

**1.**Simplify Conditional Logic****

For example like this:

```
if (dice === 6 && lastDice === 6) {
  // Player looses score
  scores[activePlayer] = 0;
  document.getElementById(`score-${activePlayer}`).textContent = '0';
  nextPlayer();
  return;
} 

if (dice !== 1 && dice !== 6) {
  roundScore += dice;
  document.getElementById(`current-${activePlayer}`).textContent = roundScore;
  lastDice = 0;
  return;
} 

if (dice === 6) {
  roundScore += dice;
  document.getElementById(`current-${activePlayer}`).textContent = roundScore;
  lastDice = dice;
  return;
}

nextPlayer();
```

**2.Delete duplicated code and extract function**

For example

```
function someFunctionName(diffRoundScore, lastDiceValue){
  roundScore += diffRoundScore;
  document.getElementById(`current-${activePlayer}`).textContent = roundScore;
  lastDice = lastDiceValue;
}

if (dice !== 1 && dice !== 6) {
  someFunctionName(dice, 0);
  return;
} 

if (dice === 6) {
  someFunctionName(dice, dice);
  return;
}
```

**3.Change check "dice for 6" to function**

```
function isDiceEqualsSix { return dice === 6};

if (isDiceEqualsSix && lastDice === 6) {
  // Player looses score
  scores[activePlayer] = 0;
  document.getElementById(`score-${activePlayer}`).textContent = '0';
  nextPlayer();
  return;
} 

if (dice !== 1 && !isDiceEqualsSix) {
  someFunctionName(dice, 0);
  return;
} 

if (isDiceEqualsSix) {
  someFunctionName(dice, dice);
  return;
}
```

**4.Change "6" to a constant variable or a function**

```
const LIMIT_SCORE = 6;

function isDiceEqualsSix { return dice === LIMIT_SCORE};

if (isDiceEqualsSix && lastDice === LIMIT_SCORE) {
  // Player looses score
  scores[activePlayer] = 0;
  document.getElementById(`score-${activePlayer}`).textContent = '0';
  nextPlayer();
  return;
}
```

I hope I helped you.

Comment: THANKS! for your careful answer. Now I barely understand the direction that I have to review. So much helpful. Which I still can not understand is 'isDiceEqualSix'. Is that only to replace 'dice === 6' or Is there some reason?

Comment: @WonkookLee 'isDiceEqualSix' is for avoiding duplicated code and direct comparison. You used comaprison 'dice === 6' twice. And more one case was 'dice !== 6'. Making this compariosom a logical function helps you to make your code more clear. You just have to use more suitable name for this function, for example 'isFinalScore' or something like this, that will be clear for another programmer. It makes code more readable.